# Install to specific directory with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am wondering if it is possible to install files to a specific directory other than the downloads folder using JavaScript.

For example, if I were downloading a video, it will install to \Videos\ rather than \Downloads.

Answer (score 3):

> I am wondering if it is possible to install files to a specific
>   directory other than the downloads folder using JavaScript.

No.  Only the end-user is allowed to specify a download location in the browser other than the default download location.  This is a security feature so web-sites and their Javascript cannot put files in locations of their choice on your hard drive (e.g. replace executables, add startup files, etc...).

Comment: better answer than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer is nope, this is not possible!